# 'useEffect' não funciona ao tentar transformar componente Stateful em Stateless

Tags: javascript, react

Eu tenho um componente que era baseado em classe, e que agora estou passando ele para ser baseado em função. O único problema que estou tendo é que, antes, eu utilizava o componentDidMount() para colocar iniciar o componente com algumas informações retiradas do backend, e agora, quando tento utilizar o useEffect para fazer isso, ele está dando como undefined. Eu também gostaria da ajuda de vocês para saber se estou fazendo a migração da maneira certa, pois sou iniciante em React.

Eis meu Functional Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import './NewsData.scss'

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/news'

const NewsData = () => {

    const [list, setList] = useState([])
    const [order, setOrder] = useState('')

    // componentDidMount() {
    //     axios(baseUrl).then(resp => {
    //         this.setState({ list: resp.data })
    //     })
    // }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(baseUrl)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => setList({ list: data }))
    })

    const renderCard = () => {
        return list.map((news, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="container" key={index}>
                    <div className="post">
                        <div className="header_post">
                            <img src={news.file} alt="posted-by-user" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="body_post">
                            <div className="post_content">
                                <h1>{news.title}</h1>
                                <p>{news.description}</p>

                                <div className="container_infos">
                                    <div className="postedBy">
                                        <span>author</span>
                                        {news.author}
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="container_tags">
                                        <span>Subject:</span>
                                        <div className="tags">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>{news.subject}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    let displayOrder = renderCard()

    if (order === "older-ones")
        displayOrder = renderCard().sort().reverse()

    const changeSelect = (e) => {
        setOrder({ order: e.target.value })
    }

    return (
        <div className="news">
            <select name="order" className="order-select" onChange={(e) => changeSelect(e)}>
                <option value="new-ones" defaultValue >Order by the older ones</option>
                <option value="older-ones">Order by the new ones</option>
            </select>
            {displayOrder}
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewsData
```

E eis o meu antigo componente baseado em classe:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import './NewsData.scss'

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/news'

class NewsData extends Component {

    state = { list: [], displayOrder: '' }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios(baseUrl).then(resp => {
            this.setState({ list: resp.data })
        })
    }

    renderCard() {
        return this.state.list.map((news, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="container" key={index}>
                    <div className="post">
                        <div className="header_post">
                            <img src={news.file} alt="posted-by-user" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="body_post">
                            <div className="post_content">
                                <h1>{news.title}</h1>
                                <p>{news.description}</p>

                                <div className="container_infos">
                                    <div className="postedBy">
                                        <span>author</span>
                                        {news.author}
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="container_tags">
                                        <span>Subject:</span>
                                        <div className="tags">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>{news.subject}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    alterarSelect(e) {
        this.setState({ displayOrder: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        let displayOrder = this.renderCard()

        if (this.state.displayOrder === "older-ones")
            displayOrder = this.renderCard().sort().reverse()

        return (
            <div className="news">
                <select name="order" className="order-select" onChange={(e) => this.alterarSelect(e)}>
                    <option value="new-ones" defaultValue >Order by the older ones</option>
                    <option value="older-ones">Order by the new ones</option>
                </select>
                {displayOrder}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NewsData
```

Agradeço pela atenção e ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é colocar a lista como objeto e não como array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        fetch(baseUrl)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            // aqui deve ser um array
            .then(data => setList(data))
})
```

Esse array é por dois motivos:

- Tu iniciou o `const [list, setList] = useState([])` ou seja o `list` vai iniciar com um array e para MODIFICAR esse array tu vai usar `setList([novoArray])`
- Tu está utilizando `list.map` se fosse fazer do jeito que tu colocou tu teria que fazer `list.list.map` afinal tu colocou um objeto no `setList`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :)